# convert two column lay out in slider on mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in my project i am working on two column layout like col-lg-8 col-lg-4 , or col-lg-6 col-lg-6 but i want when it will open in mobile view it will convert in the slider what is best solution make a separate section for mobile view or any best way for doing this

Please help me

Comment: what you have done so far? please share your code or working demo

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into using media queries. These will allow you to cater your design to the width and height of your screen.

```
/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

    }

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```

[Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)